# Read all excel files from a directory into dataframes and add a column using the file name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a folder that contains some excel files. I want to read them all to a dataframe, but at the same time adding a date column. The date is contained in each file name. I have the code to read the file content, but not sure how to read the date from file names.

This is my code to read the files.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob('my directory/*.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

I assume I need to add df['date']= but not sure how to get the date from the file names. All files names have the same format with the date at the end of the name. For example, 'Data report 06.08.21'.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: What is the format of the filename. Please post an example

Answer (score 1):

```
 import pandas as pd
 import glob, os, re

 all_data = pd.DataFrame()
 for f in glob.glob('my directory/*.xlsx'):
      _, f_file= os.path.split(f)
     file_date=re.findall(r'\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}', f_file)
     df = pd.read_excel(f)
     df['date'] =str(file_date)
     all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Is it possible to convert the 'date' column to a datetime format?

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime(file_date)`. Please, dont forget to vote for the right answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for that Alexey. I get square brackets in this new column, like this ['09.08.21']. How can I get rid of the brackets?